# How to send a string data to java webservice?

Tags: android

I have to send a long string of data through webservice to database.I odnt know how to do it.my response is

```
04-09 10:09:39.922: I/System.out(581): ********cust0=
Rajesh Kumar&cust1=
27&cust2=
 Mubarak Street&cust3=

Opposite to More Shopping Mall&cust4=
Mumbai&cust5=
10 Km&cust6=
ford fiesta&cust7=

ford fiesta&cust8=
36&cust9=
500000&cust10=
SelfUse&cust11=
No&cust12=
&cust13=

Easy&cust14=
Medium&cust15=
Good&cust16=
Good&cust17=
Flat&cust18=
Rented&cust19=

Easy&cust20=
Easy&cust21=
2&cust22=
3&cust23=
20000&cust24=
4&cust25=null&cust26=

Father&cust27=
bike&cust28=
kotak bank&cust29=
3&cust30=
3&cust31=
&cust32=
manager&cust33=

&cust34=
02223456789&cust35=
&cust36=
55000&cust37=
&cust38=
&cust39=
&cust40=
False&cust41=

&cust42=
&cust43=
&cust44=
1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM&cust45=
goodiving style&cust46=
goodiving style&cust47=

goodiving style&cust48=
goodiving style&cust49=
goodiving style&cust50=
goodiving style&cust51=
Rajesh Kumar&cust52=
27&cust55=
 Rajesh Kumar&cust56=
Rajesh Kumar
```

I have to store all these data in database by sending it to a java webservice.how can i acheive it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use all string which you send to webservice database,concat it in only one string..

after on server side string split, using StringTokenizer, and store on datbase

and plz sperate the each string using any symbol character ..when u concat

i thing this help u..